# How to prevent lambda triggered multiple times by SQS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

I have a lambda function that is triggered by SQS, but it seems that SQS triggered it multiple times even when the operation succeeded. Here is some of my code

```js
// handle.ts to handle sqs
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  
  // SQS may invoke with multiple messages
  for (const message of event.Records) {
    
    // make the call to a service 
    runAsyncService(message.body)
  }


  // ran all async call all together
  return callback(null, "succeed")
};
```

using that handler, it seems that the request is triggered 3 times (configureable, but it reaches the max retries) each with a different RequestId (which some said, indicates that the request timed out). Then, I have this code, which fixes the issue of multiple triggers.

```js
// new handle.ts to handle sqs event
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

  let jobs: any = [] // hold all async call

  // SQS may invoke with multiple messages
  for (const message of event.Records) {
    
    // make the call to a service 
    jobs.push(runAsyncService(message.body))
  }

  // ran all async call all together
  return Promise.all(jobs)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`All ${jobs.length} job(s) finished`)
      return context.succeed('Finished')
    })
};
```

as you may see, I used a `Promise.all()` function to run all the async calls, then called `context.succeed()`. Using this method had a side effect, where if there are multiple Records from sqs, if any one of the tasks fail, then the whole promise will fail, even when other tasks are successful. Calling `context.succeed()` inside the loop also is not an option, because it also triggered the call multiple times. The only option I have in mind right now is limiting the batch size to 1, but I don't really like that idea. Also, I used [getlift/lift](https://github.com/getlift/lift/blob/master/docs/queue.md) to configure sqs and lambda together. Do you guys have any suggestion for me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working solution for now is to set the batch size to 1, but it's not a solution, just a work around.